# Cocoa-touch: code seems to be skipped when additional thread used

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm new to iOS development and am following some online tutorials, the latest being on blocks and multithreading. The example application fetches photos from Flickr which the user can navigate through and view using table view controllers and a scroll view respectively.

The problem is that without multithreading, the photos are gotten from Flickr and load properly, though this is all done in the main thread. I added three seemingly simple lines of code exactly as the instructor did. His app ran properly in the demo, mine ran but now seems to skip over the code dispatched to a new thread. No pictures load.  Here's the code:

```
- (void)loadPhotos
{
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    dispatch_queue_t loaderQ = dispatch_queue_create("newphotos", NULL);
    dispatch_async(loaderQ, ^{
        NSArray *newPhotos = [FlickrFetcher getPhotos];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.photos = newPhotos;
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        });
    });
}
```

If I comment out the 3 "dispatch" lines along with the two lines closing the blocks, the code runs and pictures are loaded. As shown above, the code runs but no pictures are gotten. The debugger appears to skip the code in the blocks, so I don't believe the line: 
     `NSArray *newPhotos = [FlickrFetcher getPhotos];` 
actually runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try sticking in a breakpoint on that line to see if it gets hit?

Comment: Yes. It skips over the block. It hits the dispatch_async(loaderQ... line and then skips to the end.

Comment: I think what might be happening is that your queue is getting released at the end of the method.  You might want to make it a member variable of the class and see if that fixes you.

Comment: Gavin: I played with the debugger a bit more and found that it hits all lines of code eventually, just not when expected. @NG Thanks. I think you are right. I see now there are issues with how loadPhotos interacts with other parts of the project. I have an idea to fix it and will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dispatch_queue is getting released before it has a chance to execute anything.  You should hold onto it and release it with `dispatch_release` when done.